# Windows Store doesn't let to submit app with runFullTrust

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I've tried to submit app for Windows store, but after review it was declined with this notification:

> Desktop Bridge Apps: 98 Restricted Capability
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> You do not have approval to use the following restricted capabilities:
>   runFullTrust.  Please remove this capability from your application and
>   resubmit.

I packaged my app as it was written in Microsoft's tutorial for Desktop App Converter (DAC). Moreover, tutorial says also:

> For desktop apps that you package by using the desktop bridge, you'll
>   have to add the runFullTrust capability.

But why tutorial says "add runFullTrust" and then reviewer declines my submission, because of added runFullTrust?
I described in submission why I needed this capability, but seems like it has no influence on decision. 
P.S. My app was created using electron framework and uses chromium engine to show internet pages within my app.

Comment: Answer for my problem: I've just fixed other errors and contacted Microsoft, and then they didn't even mentioned runFullTrust capability issue. In other words, I didn't even need to fix it anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck in  some kind of "can't release yet" state and I saw the runFullTrust thing also and wondered if that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The [following MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/07/13/a-simpler-and-faster-way-to-publish-your-desktop-bridge-applications-on-the-microsoft-store/) has more details on the submission process.

Try to follow the indications from the article and it should work. Getting the above message is normal since the app is indeed using that capability and until a few months ago a MSFT employee had to manually check and approve your app.

Today, this should go a lot faster, even if you still get the notification above. From what I know MSFT should have automated the process, just as it says in the article and only if your app does not pass their automated checks you'll have to file a request for their Store team to approve the app, after they will manually test it of course.

Comment: According to the linked article, specifying "application has been packaged with the Desktop Bridge" in the submission notes should be sufficient.