# How to compile "Debugging enabled" - UWP App

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-debugging, submission

Recently my submission has been rejected which has UWP capability ( converted from desktop app to UWP with Microsoft Bridge) with a a following reason.

**How to compile the application with debugging enabled on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017?**

> Capabilities: 10.6 Restricted Capability
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> Same error, You do not have approval to use the following restricted
>   capabilities:runFullTrust. App fails to launch. just-in-time (JIT)
>   debugging instead of this dialog box. The application must also be
>   compiled with debugging enabled. Kindly re-submit the app

Comment: The windows store does not allow FullTrust for general apps, you should check how to [declare what the requirements are in the manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)

Comment: @bradbury9 It is converted by Desktop Bridge so FullTrust has been add automatically.

Comment: If the manifest is added, there should not be added FullTrust but partial one.

Comment: You need to get permission to add a "full trust" app in the Store. I don't know what the debug complaint is about. Did you ask Store support?

Answer (score 0):

> How to compile “Debugging enabled” - UWP App

To enable/disable Just-In-Time debugging:

> 1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
> 2. In the Options dialog box, select the Debugging folder.
> 3. In the Debugging folder, select the Just-In-Time page.
> 4. In the Enable Just-In-Time debugging of these types of code box,
>      select or clear the relevant program types: Managed, Native, or
>      Script.
> 5. To disable Just-In-Time debugging, once it has been enabled, you
>      must be running with Administrator privileges. Enabling Just-In-Time
>      debugging sets a registry key, and Administrator privileges are
>      required to change that key.
> 6. Click OK.

Check this document for some more details:

[How to: Enable/Disable Just-In-Time Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.85))

But I am afraid this issue is more related to submission process, you can check following thread for some more details:

[Windows Store doesn't let to submit app with funFullTrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684258/windows-store-doesnt-let-to-submit-app-with-funfulltrust)

Hope this helps.